# wso2 apimanager 1.7 Publishing HTTPS API

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Using API Manager 1.7 I have published a public API that I want subscribers to access using only HTTPS. When configuring the API I set the Transports as https only and point at a valid Rest URL for example https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

When I subscribe to the API from the API Manager Store I see my API but it has both http and https endpoints available even though I only specified https.

```
http://192.168.104.42:8280/wiki/1.0.0 
https://192.168.104.42:8243/wiki/1.0.0
```

When I subscribe to the API and test using the built in REST Client or standalone via CURL I am able to access the HTTP endpoint successfully but get a 403 Forbidden when I try and access the HTTPS endpoint. Any help resolving this issue is much appreciated?

In the server logs I see:

```
[2014-07-08 16:13:34,339] ERROR - XMLHttpRequestHostObject Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:162
)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:325)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLe
ngthInputStream.java:170)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInpu
tStream.java:108)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream.read(AutoCloseInpu
tStream.java:127)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.getResponseBody(HttpMeth
odBase.java:690)
        at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.executeRequest
(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:528)
        at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.send(XMLHttpRe
questHostObject.java:517)
        at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject.jsFunction_sen
d(XMLHttpRequestHostObject.java:278)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java
:85)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.tryit.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_
1(/store/site/blocks/api/tryit/ajax/api-tryit.jag:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.tryit.ajax.c0.call(/store/s
ite/blocks/api/tryit/ajax/api-tryit.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)

        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.tryit.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/
store/site/blocks/api/tryit/ajax/api-tryit.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.tryit.ajax.c0.call(/store/s
ite/blocks/api/tryit/ajax/api-tryit.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:3
94)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:309
1)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.tryit.ajax.c0.call(/store/s
ite/blocks/api/tryit/ajax/api-tryit.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.api.tryit.ajax.c0.exec(/store/s
ite/blocks/api/tryit/ajax/api-tryit.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.
java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:2
73)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManage
r.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:
29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDisp
atcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(Applica
tionDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationD
ispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDis
patcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:
21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(C
ompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTo
mcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoa
derValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(T
omcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValv
e.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.inv
oke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:
936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(Ca
rbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp
11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(
AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoin
t.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```